# Adding Where clause to Mysql Query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this mysql query which in fact someone on Stackoverflow gave me. (It selects the two most frequent id's found together in the columns pic1,pic2 and pic3). 
It works great but now I want to add a WHERE clause to the query so that only rows in my table where a particular ID is present are selected. ie. 
`WHERE pic1 =$loggedin_user OR pic2 = $loggedin_user OR pic3= $loggedin_user`
Can anyone tell me where the clause would go within the query below?

The  Query

```
SELECT LEAST(p1, p2) AS p1, GREATEST(p1,p2) AS p2
FROM (
  SELECT pic1 AS p1, pic2 AS p2
  FROM mytable WHERE pic1 IS NOT NULL AND pic2 IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pic1 AS p1, pic3 AS p2
  FROM mytable WHERE pic1 IS NOT NULL AND pic3 IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pic2 AS p1, pic3 AS p2
  FROM mytable WHERE pic3 IS NOT NULL AND pic2 IS NOT NULL
) s
GROUP BY LEAST(p1, p2), GREATEST(p1,p2)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Why don't you take a short look into the documentation of the sql language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Without checking the query in detail), it would go here:

```
SELECT LEAST(p1, p2) AS p1, GREATEST(p1,p2) AS p2
FROM (
  SELECT pic1 AS p1, pic2 AS p2
  FROM mytable WHERE pic1 IS NOT NULL AND pic2 IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pic1 AS p1, pic3 AS p2
  FROM mytable WHERE pic1 IS NOT NULL AND pic3 IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pic2 AS p1, pic3 AS p2
  FROM mytable WHERE pic3 IS NOT NULL AND pic2 IS NOT NULL
) s
WHERE pic1 =$loggedin_user OR pic2 = $loggedin_user OR pic3= $loggedin_user
GROUP BY LEAST(p1, p2), GREATEST(p1,p2)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This is the SELECT definition from the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

```
SELECT
[ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
  [HIGH_PRIORITY]
  [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
  [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
  [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
select_expr [, select_expr ...]
[FROM table_references
[WHERE where_condition]
[GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
  [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
[HAVING where_condition]
[ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
  [ASC | DESC], ...]
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
[PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
[INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' export_options
  | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
  | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
[FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
```